# Google Distance Matrix API

Tags: google-maps-api-3, matrix, google-api, distance, google-distancematrix-api

I was trying to use  [Google Distance Matrix API JSON](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/distancematrix/#JSON) in my project, after formatting the url, for example:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Vancouver+BC|Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco|Victoria+BC&mode=bicycling&language=en&sensor=false
```

I was able to view the result in browser, but when I tried to make a http request to get the result, I will receive status : **REQUEST_DENIED**

In documentation:

> REQUEST_DENIED indicates that the service denied use of the Distance
>   Matrix service by your application.

But I still don't know why my request is denied. More Info from google:

> Use of the Distance Matrix API must relate to the display of
>   information on a Google Map; for example, to determine
>   origin-destination pairs that fall within a specific driving time from
>   one another, before requesting and displaying those destinations on a
>   map. Use of the service in an application that doesn't display a
>   Google map is prohibited.

If I can't get the result, how can I apply it on google map?
Anyone with same problem? I will post sample code later, to clarify my question more clearly.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem, but it was due to assuming that the sensor tag would default to false, but it is in fact required.

Answer (score 2):

Google Distance Matrix API has a limit of elements set to 2500. 
I highly doubt it that you would have gone over this limit, as you would have to have calculated the maximum 10 x 10 matrix 25 times over.
I am from South Africa, and it refused to work for any local addresses until I changed the transport mode to driving (from walking, I mean seriously, we have cars). Maybe that'll help

Answer (score 1):

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

Please make sure that you have created a credentials on Google Console which can be called as "API KEY" and you are using this API KEY in above request URL on the place of "YOUR_API_KEY"

Comment: This doesn't add anything to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43280914/5211833) posted already five years ago

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem earlier.

you need to check out with the Google Api key version and codes/scripts of version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that you need is to have an API key assigned to your application. This is done by creating it in the [Google API Manager](https://console.developers.google.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to [get a Google Maps API **key**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an API KEY for using Google map services like this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=Washington,DC&destinations=New+York+City,NY&key=**YOUR_API_KEY**
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope your have enabled distance matrix API from google console for your application.

please refer

https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158841?hl=en

along with this you can restrict API_KEY for unauthorized use.